# Invalid Credentials for generating Auth Token in GoToMeeting

Tags: gtm-oauth2

I have created Trial account in GoToMeeting and I want to use restful api services. For this I need Oauth Token which I am trying to generate using the following URL:
https://developer.citrixonline.com/authentication-and-authorization
But when I enter the Username and Password, it shows an error of Invalid Credentials. But using the same credentilas I can login to https://developer.citrixonline.com without any error.

Answer (score 0):

You need to use Gotomeeting credentials, not developer portal credentials.